# Find the correct pattern in this series

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

My uncle send me a puzzle, and neither of us can solve it. The series seems to have an obvious pattern, however the given answers do not include that pattern.

-2, 4, -6, 8, -10, 12, ..., ...

- a) 39, 26
- b) 3, 16
- c) 1, 17
- d) 29, 13

I was only told what the correct answer is:

> We were told that the correct number is **c**.

Comment: Will you share *why* that answer is correct?

Comment: Probably not worth an answer, but ignoring the numbers themselves and only counting the number of "holes" in the text we get $0,1,1,2,1,0$ with the four, still distinct, answers of $1,1$ / $0,1$ / $0,0$ / $1,0$ - adding (d) results in $0,1,1,2,1,0,1,0$ and satisfies that the nth number has $-((n-1)!) \pmod n$ holes. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A061007)

Comment: @WeatherVane We were only given the correct answer. Not the reason for why it is that answer. I don't know the correct explanation.

Comment: Perhaps Uncle was looking at the solution of the next puzzle.

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps I made a typo in the question.

Comment: Is this one of a series of puzzles?  If yes, what is the difficulty of the other puzzles?

Comment: @FlorianF The other puzzles are moderately difficult, but nothing you can’t solve by trying various things for like 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I can justify:

> b) 3, 16 
>  but I do not know if it is the intended answer.

Explanation:

> Your sequence is equivalent to: 
>  15, 4, 11, 8, 7, 12 when you work in modular 17 arithmetic.

> This because in mod 17 all the negatives are just equivalent to some $p$ positive number $p=17k + n$, where $k$ is the lowest non-negative number to make the result a positive number less than 17 and $n$ is that negative number.
>  For example $-2$ is equivalent to $15 = 17*1 - 2\mod 17$ .

> Then observe that your sequence is just the composition of two sub sequences.
>  The first one:
>  -2, -6, -10, -14, -18, -22, -26, ...
>  that is equivalent in mod 17 to:
>  15, 11, 7, **3**, 16, 12, 8, 4 ... (starting from 15 subtract 4 and mod 17 everytime) 
>  And the second one:
>  4, 8, 12, **16**, 20, 24, 28, 32 ...
>  That is equivalent in mod 17 to:
>  4, 8, 12, **16**, 3, 7, 11, 15 ... (starting from 4 add 4 and mod 17 every time)

> So your final sequence is:
>  -2, 4, -6, 8, -10, 12, 3, 16, 16, 3, 12, 7, 8, 11, 4, 15, ...

Comment: That's a smart idea, but it doesn't explain why a number would sometimes be represented by its positive equivalent and sometimes not. e.g., in the "final sequence" you propose, both -10 and 7 appear.

Comment: I think I follow. However, I don't think it is consistent to say that the first 6 numbers are not in modular arithmetic, and then the next numbers are in modular arithmetic. Yours is also not the answer given as the correct solution. I edited that into my original question if you want to see it.